# Couldn't insert DATE when i import CSV file?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

i import CSV file to our database but when everything works perfect but this date columns **arrievd** **sailed** its saving in my database like **0000-00-00** 
I have a two function to import CSV file to my Database

```
private function _import_csv($path, $filename)
{
    $csv = $path . $filename;
    $query = sprintf("LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE vessels FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`job`, `name`,`port`,`arrived`,`sailed`,`principal`,`launch`,`purpose`,`pda`,`advance_pda`,`fda`,`passed`,`sent`,`fda_amount`,`fda_status`,`call_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`)", addslashes($csv));
    return DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);

}


public function postUpload (Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file')){

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadDestinationPath = base_path() . '/assets/documents/';
        $file->move($uploadDestinationPath, $name);
        return ( $this->_import_csv($uploadDestinationPath, $name) ? 'OK' : 'No rows affected' );
       //dd($this->_import_csv($uploadDestinationPath, $name));

    }

}
```

Comment: what date format of values in your csv file

Comment: could you provide an example of your raw CSV-data for clarity?

Comment: `1 0001/98 M/V SONTH GATE  01/02/1998  KAYBEE SHIPING  VESSEL ARRIVEL OPL COLOMBO FOR BUNKERING` this is one row data

Comment: date format is mm-dd-year

Comment: Thnks @MuhammadMuazzam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open csv and convert date format to YYYY-MM-DD, and then import the csv it should work.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but i found the answer before you post brother :)